# ReactJS ARIA (Accessible Rich Internet Applications ) Integration

Tags: reactjs

I am learning **ReactJS** and I want to implement **ARIA elements** so that website is accessible through **Screen Reader**. Are there any packages present to achieve this?

Expected output **(DOM Element)** :

```
<div id="percent-loaded" role="progressbar" aria-valuenow="75"
     aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100">
</div>
```

*It will be great if you an example for the same.*

Comment: Maybe take a look at some of the generic packages and see if you can't make it work? Something like https://react-spectrum.adobe.com/react-aria/index.html

Answer (score 0):

All the ARIA elements are supported in React and we don't need to add any additional package for that.

*Note that all aria-* HTML attributes are fully supported in JSX. Whereas most DOM properties and attributes in React are camelCased, these attributes should be hyphen-cased (also known as kebab-case, lisp-case, etc) as they are in plain HTML*

**Heres the link to official document**
https://reactjs.org/docs/accessibility.html